# Not showing data in edit textbox for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

I am new to asp.net mvc.  I have customized mvc identity with two more fields. Now, I would let user to update the user information like email, phone number etc. When I click on edit, I get nothing in my textbox field. HTMLEdit for textbox field is empty. for update stuff, i have to add email and then if i click submit button, the value gets change in database.

The question here is that when I click on Edit button, the user data like email is not displaying from the database before making any changes with other email id.

Here is my code

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUser(ProfileViewModels model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

            //get current user and update
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user == null)
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        user.Email = model.Email;
        user.UserName = model.Email;
        //user.LastName = model.LastName;

        var updateResult = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        if (updateResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(updateResult);

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Chtml code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateUser", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ProfileViewModels</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the GET method - how you populate and pass the model to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you show the view you need to create the model and populate it. Otherwise the view has no values to use. So something like:

```
public ActionResult UpdateUser() 
{ 
     var userModel = new UserModel();
     userModel.Email = 'Some value from the database however you are getting it';


     return View(userModel); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using @Html.TextBoxFor instead of @Html.EditorFor? Do you have a custom editor setup for email addresses?

Comment: Yes I tried. Still the value is not showing from the database.

Comment: You posted your postback code that gets the value from the model and puts it in the database. Can you post the controller method that retrieves the value from the database and populates the model?

Comment: public ActionResult UpdateUser()
        {
            return View();
        }

Answer (score 0):

You may set a break point at

```
return View(model);
```

So you can check if the model is actually empty.

I did not see how you get the model instance. 
You may add another GET action to show the initial values from the database, accepting only an Id Field. Your Edit button can call this action instead:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUser(string id)
{
  var model = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
  if (model == null)
  {
      return HttpNotFound();
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Edit button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateUser", new { id=Model.YourUserIdField })
```